# Why does modifying parent frame in Python work only for module frames?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was playing around with `inspect.stack()`. I tried modifying a local variable of the parent frame, and it seems to work only if the parent frame is module-level. The following code shows this (Python 2.7):

```
import inspect


def outer():
    a = 10 
    print a
    modify()
    print a


def modify():
    inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['a'] = 8888

outer()

a = 20 
print a
modify()
print a
```

Why doesn't it work when the parent frame is a function? Can I make it work?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm guessing it's the same reason that modifying the dict returned by `locals()` doesn't [have any effect within a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) ... IIRC, That's an implementation detail -- I'm guessing this is too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `f_locals` of a module stack frame are its `globals()`!
You can verify this by printing the `is` comparison with `globals()` inside the `modify` function:

```
def modify():
    print(inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals is globals())
    inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['a'] = 8888
```

With this change the output is:

```
$python3 modify.py 
10
False
10
20
True
8888
```

Modifying the dictionary returned by `globals()` **does** work (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958793/is-it-safe-to-modify-the-output-of-globals) question). It is *explicitly* [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) that modules implement their namespace with a simple `dict`:

> Modules are imported by the `import` statement (see section The import
>   statement). **A module object has a namespace implemented by a
>   dictionary object (this is the dictionary referenced by the
>   `func_globals` attribute of functions defined in the module).**

However the dictionary returned by [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) does *not* have to be the local namespace:

> **Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by
>   the interpreter.

In *some versions* of python2 modifying `locals()` works when using the `exec` statement inside the function. Try to add `exec ''` inside the `outer` function and see whether the output changes (it isn't guaranteed to change! However it is more likely).

Edit: On python 2.7.6 I can make it work *if* the stack frame uses the `exec` statement *and* there is no assignment to a local variable in the code. For example with `outer` defined as:

```
def outer():
    exec('a = 10')
    print(a)
    modify()
    print(a)
    locals()['a'] = 9999
    print(a)
```

I get the output:

```
$python2 modify.py 
10
False
8888
9999
20
True
8888
```

But if I add `a = 10` after the `exec` as in:

```
def outer():
    exec('a = 10')
    a = 10
    print(a)
    modify()
    print(a)
    locals()['a'] = 9999
    print(a)
```

The result is:

```
$python2 modify.py 
10
False
10
10
20
True
8888
```

I hope this shows you that the conditions in which assigning to locals work are really *few* and absolutely not reliable.

AFAIK in python3 the dictionary returned by `locals()` is *always* just a copy of the real namespace, so modifying it never works. However there is no guarantee either.

The value returned by the `f_locals` attribute is simply the value returned by `locals()` at that point.

In summary: *no*, there is **no** reliable way to modify the local namespace of a generic stack frame. You cannot modify, delete nor add new local variables to a generic stack frame's namespace.

Comment: Sweet, that explains it. Thanks!