# Modify *existing* variable in `locals()` or `frame.f_locals`

Tags: python, cpython

I have found some vaguely related questions to this question, but not any clean and specific solution for CPython. And I assume that a "valid" solution is interpreter specific.

First the things I think I understand:

- `locals()` gives a non-modifiable dictionary.
- A function may (and indeed does) use some kind of optimization to access its local variables
- `frame.f_locals` gives a `locals()` like dictionary, but less prone to hackish things through `exec`. Or at least I have been less able to do hackish undocumented things like the `locals()['var'] = value ; exec ""`
- `exec` is capable to do weird things to the local variables, but it is not reliable --e.g. I read somewhere that it doesn't work in Python 3. Haven't tested.

So I understand that, given those limitations, it will never be safe to *add* extra variables to the locals, because it breaks the interpreter structure.

However, it should be possible to change a variable already existing, isn't it?

Things that I considered

- In a function `f`, one can access the `f.func_code.co_nlocals` and `f.func_code.co_varnames`.
- In a frame, the variables can be accessed / checked / read through the `frame.f_locals`. This is in the use case of setting a tracer through `sys.settrace`.
- One can easily access the function in which a frame is --cosidering the use case of setting a trace and using it to "do things" in with the local variables given a certain trigger or whatever.

The variables should be somewhere, preferably writeable... but I am not capable of finding it. Even if it is an array (for interpreter efficient access), or I need some extra C-specific wiring, I am ready to commit to it.

How can I achieve that modification of variables from a tracer function or from a decorated wrapped function or something like that?

A full solution will be of course appreciated, but even some pointers will help me greatly, because I'm stuck here with lots of non writeable dictionaries :-/

---

Edit: Hackish `exec` is doing things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450341/1433901) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028785/1433901)

Comment: The dictionary returned by `locals()` can be modified: you are doing it in your example! And what's "hackish and undocumented" in `locals()['var'] = value ; exec ""` ? What's the point of exec-ing an empty string? And why does `exec` do weird things? In Python 3 `exec` is simply a function (like `print`), nothing special

Comment: it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/137096). What is your actual issue? Provide more context. To change a local variable e.g., a list `x`, just call its methods:`x.append("something")` or `a = 1` "changes" local variable `a` to `1`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini According to [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals): __Note__ The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.  -- And you may find some questions that take about it, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5958992/1433901)

Comment: Why don't you just store your variables in a dict? Or `if change=='a': a=v; elif change=='b'...`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I would like a technical answer. However, a plausible use case would be an automatic checkpointing framework. Which is capable to (through `trace` functions) store the state of locals and globals and proceed to resume execution in a certain point (line number) while leaving the locals and globals "correct". Specially critical if there are lines with side effects which the framework wants to avoid executing again.

Comment: @Kay I cannot change "my" variables. This is for a middleware-like application, or a framework, or something like that. For this question, I do not assume ownership on the code of the function.

Comment: @MariusSiuram: if you are a debugger; you can generate whatever code you like on the fly. Code in Python is an object; like most of the rest. Also, I see that `pdb` can change local variables (add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), though [there were/are some issues](http://bugs.python.org/issue5215).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if you can generate code on the fly but you cannot change the local variables because of some cache issues (at least I understood that), then generating code seems like no use (in this context). Thanks for the link, I will dig a little more to see what happens in 2.7 and 3.x versions...

Comment: @MariusSiuram: cache issues (with `frame.f_locals`) are unrelated to the case when you can inject code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It exists an undocumented C-API call for doing things like that:

`PyFrame_LocalsToFast`

There is some more discussion in [this PyDev blog post](http://pydev.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/changing-locals-of-frame-frameflocals.html). The basic idea seems to be:

```
import ctypes

...

frame.f_locals.update({
    'a': 'newvalue',
    'b': other_local_value,
})
ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(
    ctypes.py_object(frame), ctypes.c_int(0))
```

I have yet to test if this works as expected.

Note that there might be some way to access the `Fast` directly, to avoid an indirection if the requirements is only modification of existing variable. But, as this seems to be mostly non-documented API, source code is the documentation resource.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the notes from MariusSiuram, I wrote a recipe that show the behavior.

The conclusions are:

1. we can modify an existing variable
2. we can delete an existing variable
3. we can NOT add a new variable.

So, here is the code:

```
import inspect
import ctypes

def parent():
    a = 1
    z = 'foo'

    print('- Trying to add a new variable ---------------')
    hack(case=0)  # just try to add a new variable 'b'
    print(a)
    print(z)
    assert a == 1
    assert z == 'foo'

    try:
        print (b)
        assert False  # never is going to reach this point
    except NameError, why:
        print("ok, global name 'b' is not defined")

    print('- Trying to remove an existing variable ------')
    hack(case=1)
    print(a)
    assert a == 2
    try:
        print (z)
    except NameError, why:
        print("ok, we've removed the 'z' var")

    print('- Trying to update an existing variable ------')
    hack(case=2)
    print(a)
    assert a == 3


def hack(case=0):
    frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    if case == 0:
        frame.f_locals['b'] = "don't work"
    elif case == 1:
        frame.f_locals.pop('z')
        frame.f_locals['a'] += 1
    else:
        frame.f_locals['a'] += 1

    # passing c_int(1) will remove and update variables as well
    # passing c_int(0) will only update
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(
        ctypes.py_object(frame),
        ctypes.c_int(1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

The output would be like:

```
- Trying to add a new variable ---------------
1
foo
ok, global name 'b' is not defined
- Trying to remove an existing variable ------
2
foo
- Trying to update an existing variable ------
3
```

Comment: formally you have 'constant' declaration in Python such C++ or other languages.
I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python#2682752) helps.