# Modify variable values in bdb without ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodide

I have a class extending `bdb.Bbd` that I use for analyzing Python 3 code. Now, I need to also modify some of the variable values as it steps through the program.

Outside of functions, I can do this by just modifying the `frame.f_locals` dictionary:

```py
frame.f_locals['x'] = 2
```

I can't figure out how to do this inside functions without using the `ctypes` trick mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650744/modify-existing-variable-in-locals-or-frame-f-locals) question. I'm running Python 3 inside [Pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide) which unfortunately does not support `ctypes` yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to do this as follows. Define a Javascript function:

```js
function frameLocalsToFast(frame){
   pyodide._module._PyFrame_LocalsToFast(frame.$$.ptr, 0);
   // Hopefully avoid memory leak
   frame.destroy();
}
```

Then import `frameLocalsToFast` into Python and call it when you want to update the frame.