# Assign function-local parameter to global variable with same name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module; say it's structured as:

```
algorithms
 ├─ __init__.py
 └─ algorithm.py
```

Inside my algorithm module, I have some global vars, and I would like to create a convenience initializer that sets them up. I would like to use the same names for the initializer's parameters as for the vars, but that leads to a conflict of local and global names. The cleanest way I can think of to implement this is:

```
lower = None
upper = None

def init_range(lower, upper):
   _lower = lower
   global lower
   lower = _lower

   _upper = upper
   global upper
   upper = _upper
```

If this were a class, (I think) I could do something like `self.lower = lower`. Is there a less verbose way to do what I'm doing for module-global vars? Something like `algorithm.lower = lower`?

EDIT: Turns out my solution doesn't work.

Comment: You don't want to hear this, but your solution doesn't work and the correct solution is to avoid globals.

Comment: You're correct, it doesn't work :( but in my case, I already use globals everywhere (this is a very minimal example), and there's no time to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function to get the dictionary representing the global scope, and [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) it:

```
def init_range(lower, upper):
   globals().update(lower=lower, upper=upper)
```

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958793/is-it-safe-to-modify-the-output-of-globals), which readers should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

If you really insist on keeping the parameter names `lower` and `upper` (why not just `new_lower`, `new_upper` or something like that?) then you could delegate the task to an inner function with alternative variable names.

```
def init_range(lower, upper):
    def _init_range(_lower, _upper):
        global lower
        global upper
        lower = _lower
        upper = _upper

    _init_range(lower, upper)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lower is None, upper is None
(True, True)
>>> init_range(lower=1, upper=2)
>>> lower, upper
(1, 2)
```